# Query to return the Max(Date) and other table fields based on a primary table list

Tags: sql, vba, maxdate

I am hoping somebody out there can help me with a query problem I can’t seem to resolve;

I have two tables;

**Table1**

```
T1_ID
T1_Serial
```

**Table2**

```
T2_ID
T1_ID –lookup to Table 1
T2_Date
T2_History
```

---

Table1 Data might look something like this;

```
T1_ID   T1_Serial
1,  ABC1
2,  ABC2
3,  ABC3
4,  ABC4
```

Table2 Data might look like this;

```
T2_ID,  T1_ID,  T2_Date,    T2_History
1,  1,  05/05/15,   “Some History1”
2,  1,  05/17/15,   “Some History2”
3,  2,  05/09/15,   “Some History3”
4,  2,  05/21/15,   “Some History4”
5,  3,  05/12/15,   “Some History5”
```

I would like to set up a query to give me the record containing Max(Date) of table History for each record in table Units

Table1.T1_Serial , Max(T2_Date), T2_History;

For this example;

```
ABC1    05/17/15    “Some History2”
ABC2    05/21/15    “Some History4”
ABC3    05/12/15    “Some History5”
```

I have constructed the SQL to give me the T1_Serial and Max(Date), which is working correctly;

```
SELECT Table2.T1_ID,  Max(Table2.T2_Date) AS MaxDate
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.T1_ID;
```

But when I try adding the T2_History to the query I end up getting all the other history besides the Max(Date).

Hope someone can lead me on the right path.  Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Simply take the results you have as an inline view, alias it as a table and join from it back to table1 and table 2.

Comment: Hi xQbert, Thanks for responding.  I am not sure how to use alias in this context. So, my SQL looks like this; (sorry, struggling with formatting...)   
SELECT tbl_History.Link_RMAUnit, Max(tbl_History.Hist_Date) AS MaxDate
FROM tbl_History 
GROUP BY tbl_History.Link_RMAUnit;  How do I wrap this all together to rejoin to my initial tables?

Answer (score 0):

I use similar approach as Sam. But removed the T2_ID from the wrapped SQL to avoid issues with the GROUP BY. Also Join by Date.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1b72/6)

```
WITH MaxDate (T1_ID, MaxDate) as 
(
    SELECT T1_ID, Max(Table2.T2_Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Table2.T1_ID
)
SELECT T1_Serial, T2_Date, T2_History
FROM 
           MaxDate 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON MaxDate.MaxDate = Table2.T2_Date
INNER JOIN Table1 ON MaxDate.T1_ID = Table1.T1_ID;
```

[vba version fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0fa2/4)

```
SELECT tbl_RMAunit.RMA_SN, tbl_History.Hist_Date,tbl_History.Hist_History 
FROM ( 
  SELECT RMA_ID, Max(tbl_History.Hist_Date) as MaxDate 
  FROM tbl_History 
  Group by tbl_History.RMA_ID 
) MaxDate 
Inner Join tbl_History on MaxDate.MaxDate = tbl_History.Hist_Date 
Inner Join tbl_RMAunit on MaxDate.RMA_ID = tbl_RMAunit.RMA_ID
```

Comment: Thanks Juan,  Again, I claim a great deal of ignorance with working with SQL but I tried using your template which looks like;

With MaxDate (RMA_ID,MaxDate) as
(
select RMA_ID, Max(tbl_History.Hist_Date) as MaxDate
From tbl_History
Group by tbl_History.Hist_ID
)
Select tbl_RMAunit.RMA_SN, tbl_History.Hist_Date,tbl_History.Hist_History
From
MaxDate
Inner Join tbl_History on MaxDate.MaxDate = tbl_History.Hist_Date
Inner Join tbl_RMAunit on MaxDate.RMA_ID = tbl_RMAunit.RMA_ID
but when executing I get "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'

Comment: What sql version are you working with? Try creating that schema in SQL fiddle so I can check it. Also try running each part to see what data are you bringing or where is the error.

Comment: @JeffMitchell i think the problem is you put Hist_ID and should be `Group by tbl_History.RMA_ID`

Comment: @JeffMitchell Try this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0fa2/3 and let me know. Or update the schema there.

Comment: Juan, Thanks for setting up the sqlfiddle link. this is awesome. I did not know this tool existed. You have created the exact table format and result I am looking for but, and perhaps I should have been clear that I am using this in Access 2010 VBA, I am having trouble porting this to my SQL query. If I copy the code verbatim, I continue to get the message "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT','PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: @JeffMitchell check VBA version.

Comment: Looks like: VBA 7.0.1628

Comment: I mean check the VBA version code I put above in my answer ;)

Comment: Juan, I tested the code and got the following error; 'Syntex error (missing operator) in query expression 'MaxDate.MaxDate = tbl_History.Hist_Date Inner Join tbl_RMAunit on MaxDate.RMA_ID = tbl_RMAunit.RMA_I' . it seems to truncate the end of the expression IE: not RMA_ID. I though it might have been some buried ctrl character from the cut/paste but I got the same message even after entering the expression manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example for nested queries on VBA. But i couldnt try it. Good luck.

```
Sub TestNestedQuery()
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset, strSql As String
    Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef
    Dim qdfNew As QueryDef
    Dim strSQL1 as string
    Dim strSQL2 as string


   strSQL1 = "SELECT RMA_ID, Max(tbl_History.Hist_Date) as MaxDate " & _
             "FROM tbl_History " & _ 
             "Group by tbl_History.RMA_ID"

   strSQL2 = "SELECT tbl_RMAunit.RMA_SN, tbl_History.Hist_Date,tbl_History.Hist_History " & _
             "FROM  qryTemp " & _
             "Inner Join tbl_History on qryTemp.MaxDate = tbl_History.Hist_Date  " & _
             "Inner Join tbl_RMAunit on qryTemp.RMA_ID = tbl_RMAunit.RMA_ID "

    With CurrentDb()
        Set qdfTemp = .CreateQueryDef("qryTemp", strSQL1) '' SQL 1

        Set qdfNew = .CreateQueryDef("qryNew", strSQL2)' SQL 2

        GetrstTemp qdfNew

        ''' Delete the two querydefs if necessary
        .QueryDefs.Delete qdfTemp.Name
        .QueryDefs.Delete qdfNew.Name
    End With

End Sub

Function GetrstTemp(qdfTemp As QueryDef)

   Dim rstTemp As DAO.Recordset
   Dim i As Integer: i = 0

   With qdfTemp
      Debug.Print .Name
      Debug.Print "  " & .sql
      '' Open Recordset from QueryDef.
      Set rstTemp = .OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)


      Do While Not rstTemp.EOF
          i = i + 1
          Debug.Print rstTemp.Fields("RMA_SN")    '' Change the field name 
          Debug.Print rstTemp.Fields("Hist_Date") '' Change the field name 
          rstTemp.MoveNext
      Loop
      Debug.Print
      Debug.Print "  Number of records = " & _
      rstTemp.RecordCount
   End With

End Function
```